# making first wordpress theme, the loop and template functions not working properly

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, loops

I am following along with [this](https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/) tutorial and what I have made so far is not working as it should. I have gotten to the point where I am starting to use the loop - this is my code:

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
      <?php 
      if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

      endwhile; endif; 
      ?>
    </div><!-- /.blog-main -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  </div><!-- /.row -->
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
</div><!-- /.container -->`
```

**content.php**

```
<div class="blog-post">
    <h2 class="blog-post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <p class="blog-post-meta"><?php the_date(); ?><a href="#"><?php the_author(); ?></a></p>

    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- /.blog-post -->
```

I have two posts but only the latest post is getting displayed (by the loop) and within the post that gets displayed - the only part that is displayed is the title. So it seems like `the_date()`, `the_author()`, and `the_content()` functions are not working for some reason, and the loop is only getting one of the posts (the latest one).

What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: For post shows, please change option in WP admin, for data and content view your css styles.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I did, but I went to WP admin and clicked "customize" for the theme, and it loaded correctly in the theme editor - and then I went to the site, and it was working. I think maybe I didn't save a file, and I didn't realize it - and as I was trying to figure it out, I ended up saving the file, and it started working.